# symfony 1.4 and strange 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, apache, symfony-1.4

We have dev server and production server and it happens only in production server.

When we access the site with `http://[domain].com/index.php` , it is working fine.

But if we access with slash at the end `http://[domain].com/index.php/` , it shows `403 forbidden error`.

The strange thing is, it also shows `403 forbidden error` when there is `/xxx.php/` or `/xxx.asp/` or `/xxx.js/`. It seems it doesn't redirect to `index.php` in these cases.

If we access like `/abc/` or `/abc.a/` or etc, it redirect to `index.php` and shows `symfony 404 error` which is correct.

Anyone has experience this situation?

Comment: what os is the server running?have you checked file/folder permissions?

Comment: It is apache and I don't think it is a file/folder permissions. index.php is readable. And all the request should be redirected to index.php for handling. In my case, some request with .php/ or .js/ or .asp/ is not redirected to index.php. Instead, it seems to recognize as a folder and trying to access and got 403 error.

Comment: Can we see your htaccess and/or your vhost configuration?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

place it in your .htaccess file root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to modify your `.htaccess` file in your web root? i.e add the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way the `URL`s ending with the trailing slash will be normalized as if the didn't have it

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't work out and all css and js are gone. I think the problem is something to do with server configuration because the same code + .htaccess is working on dev server.